# Change font size in all tabs in WebView android pager

Tags: android, webview, fonts

I have 3 tabs in my activity and an icon for increase font size. In each tab, I have a webView and this is possible to increase font size with increase `webView.getSettings().setDefaultFontSize(fontsize);`.

But when I change tab, other tabs still have previous font size. how I can change 3 tabs font sizes simultaneous? and remain new size?

Comment: I think you need to take one static variable in your main activity and then assign value to it as font size and set it in every tab so on change it will reflect in all 3 tabs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS.
Save file in asset folder : styles.css

```
* {
    font-size: 100%;
  }

    htmlData = "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"style.css\" />" + htmlData;
   // lets assume we have /assets/style.css file
    webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", htmlData, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```